# Unable to open Eclipse on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

After my recent Mac OS upgrade to Big Sur , I'm unable to open Eclipse(it says Failed to create the java Virtual machine).Also I get " No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?" error on trying to build maven from terminal.

Can anyone help me with it on how it can be resolved ?

Comment: What has this got to do with IntelliJ or Visual Studio Code? What version of Java do you have installed? What does `java -version` say in Terminal?

Comment: Reinstall your JVM?

Comment: on running command "java -version" I'm getting version details i.e

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: May be the issue is with Environment Variable .... I followed proper steps for this setup but still no luck

Comment: The current Eclipse is shipped with an embedded Java, but maybe you have an outdated Eclipse version.

Comment: Older versions of Eclipse have problems on macOS 11 (Big Sur), only the current Eclipse 2020-12 works properly. This requires Java 11 but that is included as an embedded Java.